# Support for GitHub Gists in Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the GitHub API or the SO Careers, but it would be nice to have a nice ability to link to Gists that show off code. I've got a few (3, exactly) one-off code files (presented as complete, compilable class files) sitting in Gists. However, it doesn't appear that linking my GitHub account to SO Careers lets people see these exist.

I suppose I may be able to use the "Add Other Open Source Project" link, but that seems clunky. Adding a GitHub profile should allow me to show off all of my Gists and projects attached to my GitHub account.

Comment: Nope, it appears that [the current API supports getting a user's gists](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-gists)